# Implementation of HibernateRepository prodused No property 'persist'/'update' etc found for type 'YourEntity'

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jparepository

I have an entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
public class YourEntity{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "en_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "en_id_seq", sequenceName = "en_id_seq", allocationSize = 100)
    private Long id;
....
```

and when I try to implements like it's discribe on the article https://vladmihalcea.com/best-spring-data-jparepository/

```
public interface YourEntityRepository extends HibernateRepository<YourEntity>, JpaRepository<YourEntity, Long>
```

it produse No property 'persist'/'update' etc.. found for type 'YourEntity'

Is any idea?

@Overriding does not help